# How to create statistical summary for the result of clustering for different group of variable in R

Tags: r, group-by, cluster-analysis

I am wondering if there is a package or fast way to generate a statistical summary table for the result of clustering.
I imagine I can choose variables of interest and group by cluster number and then calculate mean and max and etc. I am looking for a fast way to do it. Is there any package I can use?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In my opinion, this question is much too vague. It would help a lot if you could (a) specify *exactly* what statistic you want to summarize, (b) supply a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), and (c) tell us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest and easiest way might depend on the exact results you want. The easiest approach is probably `summary()` in base R, the more versatile is to use the package `dplyr` with its functions `group_by()` and `summarize()`. For specific type of data, other packages may provide a more practical summary.

An example:

```
DF <- data.frame(groups = sample(LETTERS, 20, replace = TRUE),
                 var = runif(20))

summary(DF)

library(dplyr)
DF %>%
  group_by(groups) %>%
  summarize(mean_by_group = mean(var),
            number = n())
```